# firebase functions emulator: context.auth is undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

We are using emulators to create some local test env. We get into problem that the context.auth is always undefined.

Thanks!

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const util = require('util');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  console.log("helloWorld", util.inspect(context.auth));
  return {
    auth: context.auth
  };
});
```

This is the script code

```
 <script type="module">
    import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-app.js';
    import {getAuth,connectAuthEmulator, signInAnonymously } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-auth.js';
    import { getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator, httpsCallable } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-functions.js';
    initializeApp({
      projectId: 'demo-project1',
      apiKey: 'dummy',
    });
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function () {
      const auth = getAuth();
      connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9099");
      const functions = getFunctions();
      connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 6001);
      auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        console.log("USER CHANGED TO ", user);
        if (user) {
          callFunction();
        }
      });
      await signInAnonymously(auth);
    });

    async function callFunction() {
      const functions = getFunctions();
      const helloWorld = httpsCallable(functions, 'helloWorld');
      let result = await helloWorld({ text: "hello" });
      console.log(result.data);
    };
  </script>
```

The full example is also in GH https://github.com/eran-swimm/test-emulators
Relevant ticket
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4690

Comment: Can you log `process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST` from inside your cloud functions code? I have a feeling that the Admin SDK inside of the Firebase Functions code for `onCall` is incorrectly talking to the production server rather than the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was missing installation of firebase-admin.
When running, the emulator gave me these warnings.

```
The Cloud Functions emulator requires the module "firebase-admin" to be installed as a dependency. To fix this, run "npm install --save firebase-admin" in your functions directory.

i  functions: Your functions could not be parsed due to an issue with your node_modules (see above)
```